# app.yaml url mapping problem

Tags: java, google-app-engine, yaml

app.yaml

```
application: cloudymovie
version: 1
runtime: java

welcome_files:
  - test.jsp

handlers:
  - url: /test/*
  - servlet: com.test.TestLexerServlet
  - name: testlexer
```

test.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/test/" method="get">
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and then when i press button

```
HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /test/. Reason:

    NOT_FOUND
Powered by Jetty://
```

and i take a look in the auto-generated web.xml
i found that

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>com.test.TestLexerServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>null</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

url-pattern should not be null

I'm new in GAE.
Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/test/*` will match '/test', '/test/', '/test//', etc - probably not what you intended. Try `/test/.*` instead.

The root cause of your problem, though, is that your YAML markup isn't valid. Instead of this:

```
handlers:
  - url: /test/*
  - servlet: com.test.TestLexerServlet
  - name: testlexer
```

it should look like this:

```
handlers:
  - url: /test/*
    servlet: com.test.TestLexerServlet
    name: testlexer
```